# How to create a pivotTable in ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to create a pivotTable in ADF,but I want to use EJB instead of BC in ADF ,so someone can give me a example to shwo how to create in EJB

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you expose your EJB as an ADF Data control, it should be a simple drag and drop of the Collection onto the page and choosing table->adf pivot table as the destination.